# Is there any recommended ajax form code generation library or app?

Tags: ajax, django, ajaxform

Ajax froms are increasing becoming the industry standard. More and more frameworks like handling it natively, for example scala lift or grails.

Is there any ajax automation library in django that can generate ajax froms like this:
http://simply.liftweb.net/index-4.8.html ?

Comment: I removed my answer, as it didn't address Mr. Chen's question.

Comment: They are not the "industry standard"; as there is no such thing in the standard for HTML or XForms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what is the "AJAX form" you are referring to as the forms are simply static HTML elements. My guess is you might be thinking of ajax form validation.

In this case the static HTML code generated by Django forms is sufficient. All you have to do, is to write some JavaScript (I'd use jQuery) and handle it a bit differently server side.

please hava a look at
http://alexkehayias.tumblr.com/post/14020155360/django-form-validation-ajax

and the app for it
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ajax-forms/